# Show that a function is truly decreasing near a point $x_\circ$ if it's derivative is less than zero, using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-technique.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, epsilon-delta

**The Question:**
Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $x_\circ$ and $f^\prime(x_\circ) < 0$.
Show that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) > f(x_\circ)$ for all
$x \in (x_\circ - \delta, x_\circ)$ and that $f(x) < f(x_\circ)$ for all
$x \in (x_\circ, x_\circ + \delta)$.

**Hint:**
Note that it may be that $f$ is differentiable only at $x_\circ$ , or $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ but $f$ is not decreasing on any interval containing $x_\circ$.
Use the definition of the derivative and the fact that if the limit $L$ of a function $g(x)$ at $x_\circ$ is nonzero, then $|g(x)| > \frac {|L|}{2}$ (which you proved earlier).

**An attempt at an answer:**
By our assumption $f$ is differentiable at $x_\circ$,
so for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_\circ)}{x-x_\circ} - f^\prime(x_\circ)\right| < \varepsilon
\quad\text{when}\quad
0 < |x - x_\circ| < \delta\,.
$$
Since we are also assuming that $f^\prime(x_\circ) < 0$,
it is especially true that $f^\prime(x_\circ) \neq 0$,
so by our previous result we know that
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_\circ)}{x-x_\circ}\right| > \frac{|f^\prime(x_\circ)|}{2}\,.
\end{equation}
Now by the triangle inequality $|x - y| \leq |x| + |y|$ and our previous result,
\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_\circ)}{x-x_\circ} - f^\prime(x_\circ) \right|
&\leq
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_\circ)}{x-x_\circ} \right| +\left| f^\prime(x_\circ)\right|\\
&=
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_\circ)}{x-x_\circ} \right| +2\frac{\left|f^\prime(x_\circ)\right|}{2}\\
&<
3\left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_\circ)}{x-x_\circ} \right|\,.
\end{aligned}
Now this is where I'm stuck. Usually at this point I would have run into a situation, where  evaluating things upwards would have resulted in an expression with an absolute value $|x - x_\circ|$ times some other expression,
which I could have evaluated in one direction or the other. Obviously that is not the case here. How could one proceed in a situation like this, where there is no obvious expression $< \delta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Get rid of the absolute value.

For $|x - x_0| < \delta$  we have

$$f'(x_0) - \epsilon < \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} < f'(x_o) + \epsilon.$$

Take $\epsilon = - \frac{1}{2}f'(x_0)$ and work with the right-side inequality.

Comment: Alright, I'll see if that gets me anywhere. It might take me some time to get back to this question, since it's way past my bed time and I need some sleep.

Comment: Oh, since $\varepsilon > 0$, shouldn't I start with the left side with $\varepsilon = \frac{f^\prime(x_\circ)}{2}$?

Comment: We assume $f'(x_0)<0$, and so $-\frac{1}{2}f'(x_0)>0$.

Comment: Alright, your hint allowed me to prove that $f(x)$ must be greater than $f(x_\circ)$ when $x\in(x_\circ - \delta, x_\circ)$, for the resulting inequality to hold. Now I just have to prove the other case.

Comment: By now you see that $\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} < f'(x_0)/2 < 0$.  If you multiply both sides by $x - x0$ when $x > x_0$ you get $f(x) - f(x_0) < 0 \implies f(x) < f(x_0)$.  What happens when you multiply by $x - x0$ and $x  < x_0$?

Comment: All of the inequality relations are flipped over and I end up with $f(x) - f(x_\circ)> 0$ and therefore $f(x) > f(x_\circ)$. But this I already proved. What I am currently missing is what to do with the case $x\in(x_\circ,x_\circ+\delta)$. I assume this is the part where I have to utilize the result we derived earlier. We know that $$\left|\frac{f(x) - f(x_\circ)}{x - x_\circ}\right| > \frac{|f^\prime(x_\circ)|}{2}\ldots$$

Comment: Read the first part of my comment.  I just gave you this as well.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. My brain was insisting on me using the result that was hinted at in the question. Thank you.